# How to write a Lucene.Net RAMDirectory back to disk?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net, ramdirectory

I have been working with Lucene.Net and `FSDirectory` for some time now, so I am familiar with the basics of working with it. However, I am now attempting to rewrite some key code by using `RAMDirectory`'s when possible to speed up index use.

Loading an existing FSDirectory into a RAMDirectory is easy enough, just by using the appropriate constructor. However, I can't seem to figure out how I write it back to disk again.

I've seen some mention of a static Directory.copy() method in the Java version, but this doesn't seem to exist in Lucene.Net.

Is this possible?

**Update:** Turns out I was using an old version of Lucene.Net that didn't support this method. The "official binaries" on the official Lucene.Net site are apparently quite out of date. Thanks to CVertex for suggesting using [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) to download and install the latest version of Lucene right within Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directory.Copy static exists as per the Java version

```
public static void Copy(Lucene.Net.Store.Directory src, Lucene.Net.Store.Directory dest, bool closeDirSrc)
```

Member of Lucene.Net.Store.Directory

Perhaps you're not looking in right namespace.

Comment: Actually I think I might be using an old version, but I can't seem to find a zipped copy of anything newer on http://lucene.apache.org/lucene.net/ and I can't for the life of me figure out how to download from svn.apache.org--it just gives me directory listings (do I need to install an SVN client just to download from there?)

Comment: yes get a svn client, tortoise will do the job http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html

Comment: I recommend using NuGet and download it from there (which is what I did), which will be kept pretty up to date with the latest official releases. Using the trunk is a bit dangerous as it's always in flux as they sync with the latest Java version.

Comment: ah yes that's an even better alternative!

Comment: Thanks CVertex, that was extremely simple!